# Does docker-compose have something similar to service accounts and kubernetes-client library?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm

By creating Service accounts for pods, it is possible to access the kubectl api's of the whole cluster from any pod. Kubernetes-client libraries implemented in different languages make it possible to have a pod in cluster that serves this purpose.

Does docker-compose have something similar to this? My requirement is to control the life cycle(create, list, scale, destroy, restart, etc) of all the services defined in a compose file. As far as I've searched, no such feature is available for compose.

Or does docker-swarm provide any such features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker provides an API which can be used to interact with the daemon. In fact that is exactly what docker-compose is using to achieve the functionality provided.

Docker does not provide fine grained access control like kubernetes does, though. But you can mount the docker socket to a container and make use of the API. A good example or that is ‚portainer‘ which provides a web based UI for docker.